# Cannot register a new client ID with Instagram Developer

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am wanting to use instafeed.js on my site and need a Client_ID from Instagram.

I have watched countless tutorial videos, and know I am populating all the required fields. But am still having no success trying to register a new client with Instagram Developer.

I am definitely not entering the captcha incorrectly but I keep receiving the same error message over and over:

[image: the error messages I am receiving]

**note**: I am using my actual url, and not the url in this example.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming problem.

Comment: I'll remove the JS tag.

Comment: I am having the same problem today. Very frustrating!

Comment: Yes, I have done a bit of isolation testing and tried on a friend's account as well. I think the issue is with the captcha module itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a work-around for this:

There is an error with Instagram's captcha module on form submission. I got the form to successfully submit the first time round using Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 in Firefox 54.0.1.

No version of Safari or Chrome would work for me.

This resolved the error:

> The captcha solution was not correct. Please try again.
>
> Submission error: please fill out all required fields.

Hope Firefox solves the issue for all.

Comment: I actually had the opposite problem - Firefox wouldn't work but Chrome did. I guess the solution is to try a different browser!